# Periodic REST call failing using python httplib

Tags: python, rest, http

To monitor the server heartbeat using a REST call. I am calling  a REST api periodically every 30 seconds.

```
HEARTBEAT_URI='/heartbeat'
class HearBeatCheck:

    """
    Has other code
    """
    @staticmethod
    def check_heartbeat(host, port, username, password, timeout=60):
        http_connection = httplib.HTTPConnection(host,port,timeout=timeout)
        http_connection.request('GET', HEARTBEAT_URI, headers={'username':username,
                                                               'password':password})
        response = http_connection.getresponse()
        response.read()
        if response.status in [200, 201, 202, 203, 204, 205, 206]:
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

Now when I make this call every 30 seconds keeping the service down (heartbeat api  would return 500 or some other code) error I get using the default timeout value is CannotsendRequest error. If I modify the periodic interval to make this call in every 60 seconds I get BadStatusLine error.

Now I understand CannotSendRequest is raised because of not reading the response and reusing the same http connection object but in this case I am setting the timeout higher than the polling interval and everytime a periodic call is made a new http_connection object is used anyway. Can someone shed some light if I am missing something that is obvious? Thanks.

Comment: Have you verified (e.g. with `curl`) that the server actually responds with a correct 5xx response when the service is down? If that is the case, you should be getting neither `CannotSendRequest` nor `BadStatusLine`, but a normal response object.

Comment: Yes, I get a 500 error

Comment: I think your best bet is to step down into `httplib` with a debugger (it’s pure Python) and see what exactly causes it to behave this way.